# Ignore uppercase or lowercase letters in .htaccess files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have hosting at Hostinger.com "PHP7.4" and I'm using it as a file server for download. fastdl type. However, certain files have capital letters mixed in the name, for example:

```
http://example.com.br/fouder/Emote_Dino_Complete.mp3.bz2
```

only the program I use to search for the files sometimes searches with lowercase letters:

```
http://example.com.br/fouder/emote_dino_complete.mp3.bz2
```

and does not download.

It would be simple just to change the name of the files but there are many. I tried several configurations in `.htaccess` but without success. Would anyone have any ideas, I remember I did it years ago but I don't remember how.

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
rewritemap lowercase int:tolower
RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1} [R=301,L]
CheckSpelling on
</IfModule>
```

Comment: `rewritemap` directive is not allowed in .htaccess

Comment: "the program I use to search for the files sometimes searches with lowercase letters" - What program are you using? I assume this is _external_ to your server? And why does it only "sometimes" search with lowercase letters?

Comment: csgo game server .. the game downloads the files on the player's computer that connects to the game . I intend to use it as a file server as a backup in case the main one fails.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> rewritemap lowercase int:tolower
> RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
> RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1} [R=301,L]
> ```

`RewriteMap`s can't be defined in `.htaccess`, so this "should" result in a 500 Internal Server Error. However, converting the requested URL to lowercase is not going to help you since you would need to convert it to the same "camel case" as the underlying file (which is "unknown").

mod_speling (one "l") is really your only option (short of renaming all your files) - providing this is installed on your server. However, you have already (attempted to) enable this in your posted config file (although currently, your file is wholly invalid).

You would need just:

```
CheckSpelling On
CheckCaseOnly On
```

The `CheckCaseOnly` directive should be used to avoid mod_speling correcting other "spelling errors".

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_speling.html

Comment: I'll try to find another way via .htaccess. Hostiger only releases "mod_speling" for vip VPS.

Comment: @Анубис Is there a predictable pattern to the casing of the filename (when it is mixed cased)? eg. Uppercase first letter of each word, where each word is separated by an underscore?

Comment: @Анубис "Here's the answer"? What answer?

Comment: @Анубис There does not seem to be a discernible pattern to the filenames that have mixed case, so there's no way you can do this in `.htaccess` alone (without the use of mod_speling or listing the files one-by-one). Instead, you could rewrite the request (using mod_rewrite in `.htaccess`) to a PHP script if the initial request fails. PHP can then scan the directory for a file that matches the request, regardless of case. PHP can then offer the file for download directly (preferable) or redirect to the correct-cased filename (or fail with a 404).